# autosummary toctree, include function function details

Tags: python-sphinx, autosummary

I would like to automatically generate pages with the summary of the submodules, and the details.

I have

```
|-foo
| |- __init__.py 
| |- bar.py
|-docs
| |- conf.py
| |- Makefile
| |- make.bat
| |- index.rst
```

`foo/bar.py`:

```py
def myfunc():
    """
    This is a function.

    :return: A number.
    """
    return 1

def myotherfunc():
    """
    This is another function

    :return: A number.
    """
    return 2
```

`docs/conf.py`

```py
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(".."))

project = "foo"
copyright = "2024"
author = "Tom de Geus"
exclude_patterns = ["_build"]
extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.autosummary",
]
```

`docs/index.rst`

```
.. currentmodule:: foo

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: generated

    bar
```

This is what I get (and want in red):
[image]

In particular, I would like to add

```
.. automodule:: foo.bar
    :members:
```

to `docs/generated/foo.bar.rst`, that is currently:

```
foo.bar
=======

.. automodule:: foo.bar

   .. rubric:: Functions

   .. autosummary::

      myfunc
      myotherfunc
```